# How to mount a Docker volume to my host OS (macOS)?

Tags: docker, docker-compose, docker-volume

I persist container's data to a [volume](https://docs.docker.com/storage/volumes/) (not a [bind mount](https://docs.docker.com/storage/bind-mounts/)) and I wonder how I can inspect this data later. For example, let's say that I use something like this to run a WordPress site:

*docker-compose.yml*:

```
services:
  wordpress:
    volumes:
      - wordpress-files:/var/www/html

volumes:
  wordpress-files:
```

Is it possible to start another container (based on Alpine or something) that would mount the same volume *and* also expose it to my host OS (macOS – I'm using Docker for Mac)? Something like this (pseudocode):

```
services:

  wordpress:
    image: wordpress
    volumes:
      - wordpress-files:/var/www/html

  wordpress-files-inspector:
    volumes:
      - wordpress-files:/tmp:host

volumes:
  wordpress-files:
```

It's possible to [exec into a temporary container](https://www.freshblurbs.com/blog/2017/04/16/inspect-docker-volumes-on-mac.html) but I'd like to make the files available to my local filesystem so that I can use my local tools to browse them. Note that primarily, the files *need* to live in a named volume (for performance and other reasons) so it cannot be a bind mount like `./my-local-path:/var/www/html`.

Comment: Is the slow performance the only reason not to use a local volume? Does a named volume actually have better performance?

Comment: @BorisvanKatwijk Yes, tests run 7 minutes instead of 41.

Answer (score 1):

Why don't you just use samba? Like that:

```
services:

  wordpress:
    image: wordpress
    volumes:
      - wordpress-files:/var/www/html

  wordpress-files-inspector:
    image: dperson/samba
    command: sh -c "samba.sh -s \"mount;/mount\""
    volumes:
      - wordpress-files:/mount

volumes:
  wordpress-files:
```

You can inspect IP address of the `wordpress-files-inspector` container later (or set the container with static ip) and mount it into your host OS.

Comment: Thanks, will try that. This needs to work for all our users on different OS's but it sounds promising.